# Remove massive white space after Html tags / footer

Tags: html, css, whitespace, styling

I am getting a massive white space after the html tag or below the footer. The white space only appears on mobile device on desktop it is all fine you may have a look. Here is the link: http://webapp.musayyab-naveed.com/main/

[image]

Here is my Html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../plugins/images/favicon.png">
    <title>RGES Web App</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../plugins/bower_components/bootstrap-extension/css/bootstrap-extension.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Menu CSS -->
    <link href="../plugins/bower_components/sidebar-nav/dist/sidebar-nav.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- toast CSS -->
    <link href="../plugins/bower_components/toast-master/css/jquery.toast.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- morris CSS -->
    <link href="../plugins/bower_components/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- animation CSS -->
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- color CSS -->
    <link href="css/colors/default-dark.css" id="theme" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
    <script>
        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
            i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
            a = s.createElement(o), m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
            a.async = 1;
            a.src = g;
            m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-19175540-9', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
</head>
<?php 
    include 'php/header.php';
    include 'php/left-sidebar.php'; include 'php/breadcrumbs.php';
?>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row bg-title">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <h4 class="page-title">Dashboard</h4> </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-xs-12"> 
                    <?php echo breadcrumbs(); ?>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- .row -->
                <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="white-box">
                                    <h3 class="box-title">VERTRETUNGEN 11B</h3>
                                    <ul class="list-inline two-part">
                                        <li><i class="icon-folder text-purple"></i></li>
                                        <li class="text-right"><span class="counter">169</span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="white-box">
                                    <h3 class="box-title">ALLE VERTRETUNGEN</h3>
                                    <ul class="list-inline two-part">
                                        <li><i class="icon-folder-alt text-danger"></i></li>
                                        <li class="text-right"><span class="">311</span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="white-box">
                                    <h3 class="box-title">ANGEMELDETE SCHÜLER</h3>
                                    <ul class="list-inline two-part">
                                        <li><i class="icon-people text-info"></i></li>
                                        <li class="text-right"><span class="counter">23</span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="white-box">
                                    <h3 class="box-title">NEW Invoices</h3>
                                    <ul class="list-inline two-part">
                                        <li><i class="ti-wallet text-success"></i></li>
                                        <li class="text-right"><span class="">117</span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                <!--/row -->
                <!--.row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="white-box">
                            <h3 class="box-title">Order Status</h3>
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Invoice</th>
                                            <th>User</th>
                                            <th>Order date</th>
                                            <th>Amount</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Status</th>
                                            <th class="text-center">Tracking Number</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn-link"> Order #53431</a></td>
                                            <td>Steve N. Horton</td>
                                            <td><span class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Oct 22, 2014</span></td>
                                            <td>$45.00</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <div class="label label-table label-success">Paid</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">-</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn-link"> Order #53432</a></td>
                                            <td>Charles S Boyle</td>
                                            <td><span class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Oct 24, 2014</span></td>
                                            <td>$245.30</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <div class="label label-table label-info">Shipped</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i> CGX0089734531</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn-link"> Order #53433</a></td>
                                            <td>Lucy Doe</td>
                                            <td><span class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Oct 24, 2014</span></td>
                                            <td>$38.00</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <div class="label label-table label-info">Shipped</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i> CGX0089934571</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn-link"> Order #53434</a></td>
                                            <td>Teresa L. Doe</td>
                                            <td><span class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Oct 15, 2014</span></td>
                                            <td>$77.99</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <div class="label label-table label-info">Shipped</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i> CGX0089734574</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn-link"> Order #53435</a></td>
                                            <td>Teresa L. Doe</td>
                                            <td><span class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Oct 12, 2014</span></td>
                                            <td>$18.00</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <div class="label label-table label-success">Paid</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">-</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn-link">Order #53437</a></td>
                                            <td>Charles S Boyle</td>
                                            <td><span class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Oct 17, 2014</span></td>
                                            <td>$658.00</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <div class="label label-table label-danger">Refunded</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">-</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn-link">Order #536584</a></td>
                                            <td>Scott S. Calabrese</td>
                                            <td><span class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Oct 19, 2014</span></td>
                                            <td>$45.58</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <div class="label label-table label-warning">Unpaid</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">-</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php include 'php/right-sidebar.php';?>
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        <?php include 'php/footer.php';?>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../plugins/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="bootstrap/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/bower_components/bootstrap-extension/js/bootstrap-extension.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="../plugins/bower_components/sidebar-nav/dist/sidebar-nav.min.js"></script>
    <!--slimscroll JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
    <!--Wave Effects -->
    <script src="js/waves.js"></script>
    <!--Counter js -->
    <script src="../plugins/bower_components/waypoints/lib/jquery.waypoints.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/bower_components/counterup/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
    <!--Morris JavaScript -->
    <script src="../plugins/bower_components/raphael/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/bower_components/morrisjs/morris.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dashboard1.js"></script>
    <!-- Sparkline chart JavaScript -->
    <script src="../plugins/bower_components/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/bower_components/jquery-sparkline/jquery.charts-sparkline.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/bower_components/toast-master/js/jquery.toast.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.toast({
                heading: 'Welcome to Elite admin'
                , text: 'Use the predefined ones, or specify a custom position object.'
                , position: 'top-right'
                , loaderBg: '#ff6849'
                , icon: 'info'
                , hideAfter: 3500
                , stack: 6
            })
        });
    </script>
    <!--Style Switcher -->
    <script src="../plugins/bower_components/styleswitcher/jQuery.style.switcher.js"></script>
    <!--Style Switcher -->
<script src="../plugins/bower_components/styleswitcher/jQuery.style.switcher.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

How do I get rid of this white space on mobile? Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: so how do i fix it is there any code for it?

Comment: You are required to post your markup here within your question, not a link to your web site: [mcve] Links to your web site are useless to future users once you fix or change this problem.

Comment: I just added my Html

Comment: You totally skipped the "minimal" part and you show no CSS and there are errors in your javascript.

Comment: [link](http://webapp.musayyab-naveed.com/main/css/style.css)   Here is my css

Comment: Again, you are required to post your markup here, not your web site!

Answer (score -2):

Try making the css of the div that follows the head-div

```
position: fixed;
top: 5%;
```

(Adjust the % as you need according to the size of the top div)

Comment: which head-div are you talking about?